# Apply Counter on numpy arrays to get columns mode

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an three numpy array's

```py
import numpy as np

a=np.array([1,2,4,4])
b=np.array([1,3,4,3])
c=np.array([1,2,3,3])
```

I need output like

```py
array([1,2,4,3])
```

Where the value at index i in the most frequent element in the column i.e.

- In the first column 1 appears highest number of times;
- In the second column: 2 appears the highest number of times;

and so on..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter` in the following way.

```
from collections import Counter
result = []
for i,_ in enumerate(zip(a,b,c)):
  count = Counter([a[i], b[i], c[i]])
  result.append(count.most_common(1)[0][0])
```

`result` will give `[1,2,4,3]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the scipy dependency, you can use the built-in function [scipy.stats.mode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html) along the 0-axis of the stacked arrays. Ohterwise you can use [numpy.unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) or [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) along the columns of the stacked array.

**Scipy Mode**

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode
from collections import Counter

a = np.array([1,2,4,4])
b = np.array([1,3,4,3])
c = np.array([1,2,3,3])

m = np.vstack([a,b,c])

mode(m, axis=0)[0]
array([[1, 2, 4, 3]])
```

**Numpy Unique**

```py
modes_numpy = []

for c in m.T:
    vals, counts = np.unique(c, return_counts=True)
    index = np.argmax(counts)
    modes_numpy.append(vals[index])

modes_numpy
[1, 2, 4, 3]
```

**Collections Counter**

```py
modes_counter = []

for c in m.T:
    modes_counter.append(Counter(c).most_common(1)[0][0])

modes_counter
[1, 2, 4, 3]
```